# jQuery - how to select a variable's suffix and find its match in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of options:

```
var options = ["foo_A", "foo_B", "foo_C", "foo_D"];
```

...and when a user clicks on one of the following elements...

```
<div id="bar_A"> </div>
<div id="bar_B"> </div>
<div id="bar_C"> </div>
<div id="bar_D"> </div>
```

...it sets the following variable:

```
var currentBar = $(this).attr('id');
```

...and then I'd like to search through the options array and find the item whose suffix matches that of currentBar, something like this:

```
 $.each(options, function(i,v){
 if (v's suffix matches the currentBar's suffix){

 //function to do something

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each(options, function(i,v){
    if (options[i].split("_")[1] == currentBar.split("_")[1]){

   //function to do something

}
```

Comment: Mistake at `"_"[1])` need to be `"_")[1]`

Comment: Second mistake: Just `v` or `options[i]` instead of `v[i]`

Comment: @Niko v contains the value of the current element during each iteration.

Comment: @Chibuzo Exactly, so what sense did `v[i]` make there?

Comment: @Niko lol, that was an error. v could have done the job. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `split` function on currentBar

```
var Extract = currentBar.split('_');
// Extract[0] will be bar and Extract[1] will be the letter
```

After, second value will be the letter and will match.

```
var Key = indexOf('foo_' + Extract[1], options);

alert(options[Key]);
```

Comment: `options` is a regular array, so you need to use `$.indexOf()` in the end.